# Why one pin of AC voltage is grounded in industrial application?

Tags: ac, grounding

I have an industrial IO module that is an extension of PLC. The datasheet says that if connected  AC voltage, you must make one pin is grounded. Why need it be grounded? Why don't they use a bridge diode to rectifier AC voltage in their circuit? Is this done to prevent GND differences between modules?

Updated:

```
Important:
• power the module with AC voltage only, with the
transformer secondary winding earthed;
• if the Ethernet connection is featured and used, the transformer
secondary must be earthed;
• using a supply voltage other than specified can seriously damage the
controller;
• if the transformer secondary is earthed, make sure that the earth
conductor is connected to terminal G0. This applies to all the devices
connected to the module through a serial network;
• if more than one board is connected to a LAN network, make
sure that the G and G0 references are observed (G0 must be maintained
for all controllers);
• the power supply to the controller(s) and the terminal(s) should be
kept separate from the power supply to the other electrical devices
(contactors and other electromechanical components) inside the
electrical panel.
```

[image]

Comment: Link to user manual, please, in your question.

Comment: @Gokhan - "*The datasheet says that if connected AC voltage, you must make one pin is grounded.*" That's not what the diagram implies to me. You state that the datasheet "**says**" that a connected AC voltage must have one pin grounded. In that case, please add a link to the datasheet and quote the relevant specific words from the datasheet which tell you that.  Or did you mean that this is your interpretation of the *diagram* that you included? In that case please, again, add a link to the datasheet. Thanks.

Comment: The message has been updated with the important message in the datasheet.

Comment: Two of us asked for a link to the datasheet. You've just provided an extract. We don't even know what brand it is. Context can matter.

Comment: Datasheet confidential document is forbidden, so I cannot publish it.

Answer (score 0):

This appears to be the power source for the module.

Edit: The text really throws a monkey wrench into the diagrams.

My guess is that the Ethernet shells are probably connected inside the module to G0 and not maintaining that point at ground on all connections can lead to noise issues or even smoking the cable if it is shielded.

The text is self-contradictory, however, so user beware. You might want to confirm your proposed wiring diagram directly with the manufacturer.

Comment: The message has been updated with the important message in the datasheet.